# Is there a way to find out if a site is blocking Tor?

Tags: censorship

I'm seeking something like https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/, but for testing if a site is blocking Tor requests. Does such a beast exist? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Netflix blocks all exit nodes. Use it as a test URL.

Comment: Just try going to the website. If they are blocking Tor, you'll get a message saying your IP has been blacklisted, or something similar.

Comment: @SuperSluether Sadly, this isn't always the case. Some seem to just drop packets on the floor, so you just sit there waiting for timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

for that purpose I use the following site:

- https://web-capture.net/
- http://isup.me/

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would I use these two sites to find out if a site is blocking Tor?

Comment: I use tor to connect it, if I have problems I try that sites. If the sites I want test is up and running tor is blocked.

Comment: an interesting approach - use the first site (web-capture.net) to download an image of a site, then see if you can access the same site via Tor, which can all be done with within Tor. Not a direct answer to my quest, but interesting!